# Why don't the conda and anaconda packages have the same version?

Tags: anaconda, conda

When I install Anaconda 3 I got the version 5.1.0 of it but when I run `conda info`  I realise that conda version is not 5.1.0 but 4.4.10. Why aren't these the same version?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the `anaconda` package and the `conda` package is that:

1. The `anaconda` package is what's called a "meta-package". This means that it doesn't have any packages inside of it; rather, it contains a (long, in this case) list of version specifications of other packages (NumPy, Matplotlib, SciPy, etc.) that are installed when you write `conda install anaconda`. The `anaconda` meta-package has the version 5.1.0 (as of this writing) and this is the same version as the Anaconda installer you download.
2. The `conda` package contains the code for the `conda` executable scripts, basically all the code that is necessary to process commands such as `conda install ...`, `conda create ...`, `conda info` and so forth. It is a separate package from `anaconda`, and thus, has a separate version number.